# backtrace() replacement for uClibc i386

Tags: c, stack-trace, static-linking, uclibc

I'm compiling a statically linked i386 binary for Linux, using uClibc. The *backtrace* library function to generate a stack trace of addresses is not available. I need a replacement.

Both http://code.metager.de/source/xref/lib/eglibc/libc/sysdeps/i386/backtrace.c and https://github.com/hwoarang/uClibc/blob/master-metag/libubacktrace/backtrace.c seem to load the function *_Unwind_Backtrace* from `libgcc_c.so.1`. However, `libgcc_so.1` is not available in my toolchain, and when I try to use *_Unwind_backtrace* directly, I get a stack trace of only 1 frame (the topmost one, from the function calling *_Unwind_Backtrace*.

I need a working replacement for *backtrace* or *_Unwind_Backtrace* in my statically linked i386 Linux executable, linked against uClibc, without loading any .so files (such as `libgcc_c.so.1`), which can generate a full stack trace (only the instruction pointers). Where is such an implementation available?

FYI for gcc `__builtin_return_address` generates code like this:

```
    movl    0(%ebp), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax 
    movl    (%eax), %eax 
    movl    (%eax), %eax 
    movl    (%eax), %eax 
    movl    (%eax), %eax 
    movl    (%eax), %eax 
    movl    (%eax), %eax 
    movl    4(%eax), %eax
```

This just blindly walks up the frame chain, without any bounds checking or sanity checking. I'd like to use something safer than that.

Please note that even glibc *backtrace(3)* doesn't display frames in functions compiled with *gcc -fomit-frame-pointer*, I've decided that I don't need that.

Comment: This is somewhat hackish but it should work with GCC(-compatible compilers): [execinfo.c](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/browser/lib/libvarnishcompat/execinfo.c?rev=6ea89fd1ed370ffab7af3ac871bba20f4bbfac7e)

Comment: @user3477950: Thx. It looks like __builtin_return_address(i) just blindly walks up the ebp chain. I've updated the question.